# What does hot spot in Qt drag-and-drop mean?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt

Qt has a method `QDrag::setHotSpot()` which

> sets the position of the hot spot relative to the top-left
>   corner of the pixmap used to the point specified by hotspot.

But what is hot spot and its function? How would you define it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hotspot basically defines where the dragged pixmap shall be located while the drag operation is on-going.

Have a look at this [drag & drop example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-draganddrop-draggableicons-example.html) to see how it is typically used.

Answer (score 3):

> We also specify the cursor's hot spot, its position relative to the
>   top-level corner of the drag pixmap, to be the point we calculated
>   above. This makes the process of dragging the label feel more natural
>   because the cursor always points to the same place on the label during
>   the drag operation.

```
 QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
 drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
 drag->setPixmap(*child->pixmap());
 drag->setHotSpot(hotSpot);
 child->hide();
```

[Fridge Magnets Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-draganddrop-fridgemagnets-example.html)

Comment: "This makes the process of dragging the label feel more natural because the cursor always points to the same place on the label during the drag operation." What would happen without a hot spot? The cursor would point to different places on the label during the drag operation each time instead?